# Report on data in SQL database that does not meet certain rules

Tags: stored-procedures

I need to generate reports in a web app for rows in my tables that do not meet specific rules. I want to allow the data to be inserted into the tables, but I want to be able to flag it so that a user can return later and correct it. An example of some of the rules I'm checking against are that strings are in certain formats and lengths (like a license plate) and I'm also checking for validity on dates. I expect to have more of these rules come up in the future, so I'm looking for a scalable solution. My application is in .NET, but I've been told it would be better to do this on the DB side rather than in code. Should I be looking into implementing some type of rules engine with stored procedures?

Comment: @RDFozz - you should add that as an answer so it can be up/downvoted, commented-on, and selected as the accepted answer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to maintain some sort of flag indicating which rows have problems (which makes sense if you have a lot of rows, 99.9%+ of which will be fine), then I'd use a trigger to check for the conditions. That way there's one check, only done when a row is actually added or changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of this may depend on some specifics of your situation (future needs for the application, performance, data size, ease of maintenance, etc.) but generally I like to, when possible, do the check at both the database and app layer. This ensures that if one of the two get changed down the line for whatever reason, it is unlikely that you (or whoever is now maintaining this) doesn't lose this validation, but since you want to allow bad data it is a little trickier.

This will seriously affect the integrity of your data and make things harder in the long term for you and the application. I'd recommend enforcing constraints to not let them enter bad data in the first place in at least some, if not all of the cases.

In that vein, I tend to shy away from triggers unless they're absolutely necessary since they can become a slippery slope to performance issues, but they may be viable for your needs. You may also want to check out [User Defined Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/user-defined-data-type) for something like a license plate number in addition to application validation logic.

If you simply *must* let them enter bad data, I'd probably leverage a stored procedure to handle the validation logic and (presumably) bit flags to designate invalid values. I hate business logic in my database, but if I have to do it stored procedures are generally the best place to put it IMO.